# asp.net application high cpu, high requests/sec

Tags: asp.net, response, performance-testing, cpu-usage

I am testing an asp.net web application iis7.Appserver- dual core,8gb, Webserver -dualcore 8gb.Running with 50 users for 1 hour.Requests/sec is 550 and CPU maxes out.  Requests queue & current are 4 and 21 on an average. We run on default configuration. Number of logical and physical threads on webserver are 55 and 48 on an avg.Private bytes consumed went up to 0.4gb by end of load test.# of Exceps thrown/sec increases but errors total/sec is 0. Cache total turnover rate is high.% GC time is 4.73 on an avg.There are no errors in the load test and no. of passed transactions are also good.The concerns that we have are:
-How to improve the response time
-Should we limit the request/sec and are we stressing the server coz of high no. of requests
-Is 50 users high for the current configuration.We dont have any biz requirement or SLAs as of now.
I changed the process config to he following and that improved the resp time by 1-4 secs.

```
 memoryLimit="60" 
   autoConfig="false" 
   maxWorkerThreads="100" 
   maxIoThreads="100" 
   minWorkerThreads="40" 
   minIoThreads="30"
```

Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that your choice of values does not come from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/821268 So please spend some time on KB821268.. Besides, ASP.NET classic (not ASP.NET Core) does have its performance limitation, so you have to also switch to its async model to speed it up and upgrade to ASP.NET Core if you really need the extreme. A 2 core web server is almost itself a limitation, as a web server usually requires more cores, based on KB821268's indication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net web-service high CPU usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584490/asp-net-web-service-high-cpu-usage)

Comment: This question does not seem to be about programming. You *might* have better luck at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) or [webmasters.se], but please do read the help center for both sites first.